# Run npm scripts in Eclipse

Tags: node.js, eclipse, npm

I have the following `package.json` file that works fine in IntelliJ that I am trying to get to work in Eclipse:

```
{
  "name": "backend_server",
  "keywords": [],
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node-dev --cache-directory tmp --respawn --transpileOnly src/index.ts",
    "start2": "cross-env NODE_ENVIRONMENT=production ts-node tmp/ --respawn --transpileOnly src/index.ts",
    "start": "node dist/bundle.js",
    "build": "webpack",
    "remove-js-files": "cd src && del /s /f /q *.js",
    "testBuild": "webpack && node dist/bundle.js",
    "test": "jest",
    "compile": "del /s /f /q build && tsc"
  },
[...]
```

In IntelliJ with the NodeJS plugin installed, each of the scripts has an ▶ next to it that can be used to generate a working run configuration for that script. However, I have yet been unable to figure out a way to get it to work in Eclipse.

What I have tried so far is install the Nodeclipse and Enide plugins and try to set up a working run configuration. The closest I've come is this:

`Run As` > `npm ...` with Goal: `run-script` returns this:

```
Lifecycle scripts included in backend_server:
  start
    node dist/bundle.js
  test
    jest

available via `npm run-script`:
  dev
    ts-node-dev --cache-directory tmp --respawn --transpileOnly src/index.ts
  start2
    cross-env NODE_ENVIRONMENT=production ts-node tmp/ --respawn --transpileOnly src/index.ts
  build
    webpack
  remove-js-files
    cd src && del /s /f /q *.js
  testBuild
    webpack && node dist/bundle.js
  compile
    del /s /f /q build && tsc
```

However, trying to actually run one of those scripts via `Run As` > `npm ...` with Goal: `run-script dev` returns this:

```
Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:
    access, adduser, audit, bin, bugs, c, cache, ci, cit,
    clean-install, clean-install-test, completion, config,
    create, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, doctor,
    edit, explore, fund, get, help, help-search, hook, i, init,
    install, install-ci-test, install-test, it, link, list, ln,
    login, logout, ls, org, outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix,
    profile, prune, publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root,
    run, run-script, s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star,
    stars, start, stop, t, team, test, token, tst, un,
    uninstall, unpublish, unstar, up, update, v, version, view,
    whoami

npm <command> -h  quick help on <command>
npm -l            display full usage info
npm help <term>   search for help on <term>
npm help npm      involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    C:\Users\Kira Resari\.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@6.13.4 C:\Programs\nodejs\node_modules\npm

Did you mean this?
    run-script
```

Thus, I am stumped as to how I should use this runner, or if it is even the correct runner to use. Obviously, `run-script` recognizes that there are runnable scripts available, but apparently leaves me with no options to run them.

Summed up: What do I have to do in order to be able to run, say, the `dev` script in the above configuration in Eclipse?